# Sampling with no duplicates

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation, sampling

I am sampling a population of unknown size and unknown distribution. The sample will be taken over distinct time intervals, but I have to reject any duplicates in the given time interval. The sample sizes over each time interval will vary in size. The sample will then be combined to form the population sample. My goal is to estimate the size of the population.

Example:

Time period 1) $\{x_1,x_4,x_8,x_8,x_8\}$ reject fourth and fifth observation and I am left with $\{x_1,x_4,x_8\}$ as my sample in time period 1.

Time period 2) $\{ x_{10}, x_1, x_7,x_3, x_8, x_{10}, x_{11}, x_7 \}$, reject sixth and eight observations and I am left with $\{ x_{10}, x_1, x_7,x_3, x_8, x_{11} \}$ as my sample in time period 2.

I now combine my sample from time periods 1 and 2 to get $\{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_7, x_8, x_8, x_{10}, x_{11} \}$

My question concerns the process that I am following. It appears to be selection bias. What can I do to address it? Is there some way to weight the samples with multiple duplicates more heavily when I make my estimation. Are there any other issues I should be aware of?

Comment: What are you trying to model/estimate/test?

Comment: I am trying to estimate the usage of a product. There may be many users at the same time or no user for a given time. It is a big data question, the stuff is proprietary so I can't give too much information, just general stuff. I only included the time component for simplification, but there is a space component as well. The point of the exercise is to estimate the number of unobserved users.

Comment: If what you are trying to do is estimate a total population from your samples, then one approach might be a [capture/recapture analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture) though there may be underlying assumptions such as equal probability of capture which might not apply in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This could serve a place to start, but unfortunately my data is not uniform.